# Cross reference of an inline equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, cross-referencing, inline

Consider the equation

```
\begin{align*}
        \dot{x}_i(t)=f_i\left(x_1(t),\ldots,x_N(t)\right) \\
        + g_i(x_1(t),\ldots&,x_N(t))u_i(t),\tag{$\Sigma_i(u_i)$}\label{eq:subsystem}
\end{align*}
```

When $\Sigma_i(u_i)$ is closed loop with a function $\phi_i$, it is denoted as $\Sigma_i(\phi_i)$. How can make a reference for the notation $\Sigma_i(\phi_i)$?

Kind regards,

Comment: Use `\align`, not `\align*` when you need to refer to an equation.

Comment: I prefer \align* as I do want to mess with the equation counter

Answer (score 1):

Using your own tag doesn't increment the equation counter:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
        \dot{x}_i(t)=f_i\left(x_1(t),\ldots,x_N(t)\right) \notag \\
        + g_i(x_1(t),\ldots&,x_N(t))u_i(t),\tag{$\Sigma$}\label{eq:subsystem}
\end{align}

Now I can refer to equation \ref{eq:subsystem}.

Here's another equation with a number:
%
\begin{equation}
2+2 = 4.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Ethan. Unfortunately, that quite not answer the question. The problem is how to refer to $\Sigma_i(\phi_i)$ without this equation being written.

Comment: @Humberto I don't understand. Can you edit your question to include a complete document that _looks_ like what you want, even though you can't yet make that happen automatically?

Comment: @Humberto PS By "complete document" I don't mean your whole paper. Just a small compilable example that illustrates your problem.

Comment: `equation~\ref{eq:subsystem}`